# clock pulse generator for a PLC

Tags: clock, plc

I am working with PLCs trying to design a water tank. On one section of the design I am asked to create a clock pulse generator. I am currently trying to do this using ladder diagrams.

I believe I have the logic correct just cant seem to put it together. I want a counter to count the clock pulses that I generate, then I store these pulese in a data memory to ensure the count is retained if the system is switched off and on.

question is how do I design this clock pulse generator.

Kind regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few different ways to create a pulse generator (or commonly known in the plc world as a BLINK timer).  As a matter of fact many plc programming softwares have this function block built in to their function block libraries.  But if they don't or you just want to make your own you can do something like this

```
VAR
  ton1: TON;
  ton2: TON;
  StartPulse: BOOL;
  startPulseTrig: R_TRIG;
  LatchPulseInitial: BOOL;
  PulseOutput: BOOL;
  Timer1Done: BOOL;
  Timer2Done: BOOL;
  PulseWidth:TIME:=t#500ms;
END_VAR
```

[image]

If  you would like to count the number of pulses and store this value to a variable you can use a simple CTU (counter up) block available in all plc languages.

[image]

**Review of functionality**

1. The `StartPulse` variable can be anything you want that will start the counter.  In my case I just used an internal `bool` variable that I turned on.  If you want this timer to start automatically when the plc starts then just initialize this variable to `true`.  Because `StartPulse` only works on the rising edge of the signal the `LatchPulseInitial` coil will only ever be set once.
2. When the `LatchPulseInitial` variable goes true this will start `ton1` a `Timer On Delay (TON)` function block.  This will delay the output of the block from turning on for the time of `PT` (in my case I have 500ms).
3. After 500ms has expired the `ton1` outputs will turn on.  this will turn on the `Timer1Done` variable and turn off the `Timer2Done` and `LatchPulseInitial`. Now that `LatchPulseInitial` has been turned off it will never interfere with the program again since it can only be turned on by the rising edge of `StartPulse`.   **Note: once the block has reached `PT` the outputs will stay on until the input to the block is removed.**

[image]

4. Since `Timer1Done` is now on `ton2` will start counting until `PT` is reached.  Once `PT` is reached the outputs for that block will turn on. This will reset `Timer1Done` and set `Timer2Done`  This will start `ton1` again and thus starting the whole process over.
5. For the `PulseOutput`, which is the actual pulse output you are looking for, I have this being set to true when `Timer2Done` is true.  This is because when this variable is `true` it is the high state of the pulse generator.  When `Timer1Done` is true it is the low state of the pulse generator.
6. When the `PulseOutput` goes `true` it will trigger the input on the `CTU` which will increment the count of the variable in `CV (current value)` by 1.

If you are going to be using this logic in numerous places in your program or you plan on reusing it in the future I would make this into its own function block so you won't have to repeat this logic everytime you want to make this type of timer.

Comment: Thanks mrsargent! Just a couple of questions and a few things to clear up. My design project asks us to use the pulse we create ( from the clock pulse generator) to count up a counter and then store the number of pulses in data memory. Firstly when you say ' start the pulse generator on the rising edge of the startpulse input' are you using the internal PLC clock to do this?
secondly I am unsure as the function of the two blocks ton1 and ton 2 ? what do they do? sorry for any basic questions.

Comment: Thanks mrsargent, brilliant answer very informative! Just two more things sorry :) is it possible to achieve the same result, but with using one TON with a PT of 1 sec? and what do the (r) and (s) mean in reference to latchpulseinitial timer1done and timer2done. Thank you kindly

Comment: Yes it is possible to do this with one TON but would require some different logic.  That may be another post entirely.  For your second question, R and S refer to Reset and Set.  These are very common in ladder logic programming.  Essentially Set means to set something to `true` and Reset means to set something to `false`.

Comment: Thanks again! I thought it was set and reset. For my solution I need the counter to go up one every second. If I was to remove the second TON and just have the Timer1Done signal set the pulse output signal, which then updates the counter..would this achieve same result? or is it bad practice? Kind regards :)

Comment: If you set the time on the function block `PulseWidth` to 500ms then it will count every second.  This is because it counts only when the signal transitions from `false` to `true`. So it would work like this (1) signal would turn on and 500ms would elapse.(2) Signal would turn off and 500ms would elapse.  Signal would turn back on again after a total of 1000ms.  So it would update the counter every second if you set the time to 500ms.

Comment: Thank you :) I think that is just what I need!

Answer (score 1):

Once I had to create a BLINK FB. It is written in Structured Text. But it is suitable to use in a ladder logic program and IN/OUT Variables are named like TON style. The Blink starts with Q = TRUE. If you want to start with FALSE just invert Q and switch the Times!

```
FUNCTION_BLOCK BLINK
    VAR_INPUT
        IN : BOOL;
        PT_ON : TIME;
        PT_OFF : TIME;
    END_VAR
    VAR_OUTPUT
        Q : BOOL;
        ET : TIME;
    END_VAR
    VAR
        rtIN : R_TRIG;
        tonBlink : TON;
    END_VAR
```

---

```
rtIN(CLK := IN);

IF tonBlink.Q OR rtIN.Q THEN
    (*Toggle Output*)
    Q := NOT Q;
    
    (*Timer Reset call, important to call timer twice in same cycle for correct Blink Time*)
    tonBlink(IN:= FALSE);
    
    (*Set corresponding Time*)
    IF Q THEN
        tonBlink.PT := PT_ON;
    ELSE
        tonBlink.PT := PT_OFF;
    END_IF
    
END_IF

(*Timer Run call*)
tonBlink(IN:= IN);

IF IN THEN
    ET := tonBlink.ET;
ELSE
    ET := T#0S;
    Q := FALSE;
END_IF
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, this is the most straightforward way to do it, using 1 timer, up counter and modulo operator:

[Blink function in ladder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CdZge.png)

Also note, if your PLC doesnt have modulo, then multiply by -1 each time.